# iAd iOS 7 delegate methods not getting called

Tags: delegates, iad, interstitial

If I create a new single view project in XCode 5.0.2, add the iAd Framework, implementing the ADInterstitialAdDelegate in ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ADInterstitialAdDelegate>

@end
```

and the delegate methods in ViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [ self performSelector:@selector(onDelay) withObject:nil afterDelay:2 ];

}

-(void)onDelay
{

    self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicyManual;

    [ self requestInterstitialAdPresentation ];

}

-(void)interstitialAd:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"interstitialAd didFailWithError");
}

-(void)interstitialAdDidLoad:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd
{
    NSLog(@"interstitialAdDidLoad");
}
```

**none of the ADInterstitialAdDelegate methods are called**. I'm also experiencing some problems using the old implementation in iOS 6 and below

```
interstitial = [[ADInterstitialAd alloc] init];
interstitial.delegate = self; 
[ interstitial presentFromViewController:self ];
```

Only

```
-(void)interstitialAdDidLoad:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd
```

is called then, but no

```
- (void)interstitialAdDidUnload:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd
```

after closing the ad. Does anybody remember having the same problems or know what's going on here?

Comment: Hi, I just got into using *requestInterstitialAdPresentation*. I believe using this does not call the usual ADInterstitialAdDelegate methods. I don't know how to get a similar load/unload method call..

Comment: Any update on this? I'm not sure how to detect if a user tapped or dismissed an ad...

Comment: Mine is not calling as well. Funny thing is that it just only appears once and I have to re-run the app to see it again. I am in development stage.